# Shrinking a circular buffer

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, circular-buffer, circular-list

I'm trying to implement the shrinking operation for a circular buffer. 
The buffer has a start pointer( m_start ) and stores the number of elements( m_numelements). When the buffer is full I just purge the old value.

Say we have a array of size 16. 
m_start = 9 
m_numelements = 11.

I want to shrink this array into an array of size 8( Can discard elements ).

The constraint here is that m_start( 9 ) of the old array should map to the m_start % new capacity ( 9 % 8 = 1 ) of the new array.

I tried writing the code but ended up with a lot of if-else ladder. Any efficient implementation for this ?

Comment: I have a similar problem. Would I be allowed to edit the question to use a more concrete implementation (in C), probably forcing some answer proposals (none accepted to far) to be updated as well, or should I ask a new question?

Answer (score 1):

Let's storage array has zero-based indexing, and it's size is power of two (2,4,8...), m_start is start index.

When array is growing:

```
 double array length
 if m_start > 0 then
    copy (m_start elements) from (0th index) to (old size index)
```

example:

```
  3 0 1 2|. . . .
  . 0 1 2|3 . . .
```

When array is shrinking:

```
  if m_start > 0 then
     copy (m_start elements) from (newsize index) to (0th index) 
  half array length
```

example:

```
  . 0 1 2|3 . . . 
  3 0 1 2|. . . .
```

You can modify this scheme for one-based array indexing.

Answer (score 0):

Shrinking is equivalent to dequeueing the entire contents into a temporary buffer, and then enqueueing the contents of that buffer into a new circular buffer with the specified capacity.  This isn't quite what you want, but it will inform what the code must look like.

So: write code to dequeue the entire contents of a circular buffer and enqueue them into a new circular buffer by using methods you already have, then inline the code contained in the methods you used, then refactor that code to place the contents into the existing circular buffer (after resizing) instead of a new one and optimize away any unnecessary copies or cases.

Comment: For a huge number of items this may be inefficient regarding time and memory. Maybe see the image in https://stackoverflow.com/a/70659033/6607497 for some cases where it can be done much more efficiently.