# Seeking algorithm for "dual-modulo array memmove"

Tags: arrays, modulo, memmove

As the algorithm being requested is somewhat special, I'm trying to explain what I want first, then I'll ask concrete questions that I'm quite unsure about:

### Introduction

The algorithm is not C-specific, but I'll start with a C-example, namely `memmove()`:
Memmove can copy a region of memory to another, handling overlaps correctly.
Basically, it means that if the source-destination address is lower than the source address, the first item will be copied and the index increases; otherwise the last item is copied, and the index decreases.
So the ordering of the memory regions is important.

### Problem

I want to move regions in an array-based ring buffer, that is a region may wrap at the end of the array, making it a lot harder to decide which region has a lower address.
To make things even more complicated the actual modulo value being used for source and destination may be different.
Let's go concrete, and assume this C prototype (just for clarity):

`mod_move(item_t items[], unsigned s_i, unsigned d_i, unsigned s_mod, unsigned d_mod, unsigned len);`

`items[]` holds the *data items*.
`s_i` is the *source index*.
`d_i` is the *destination index*.
`s_mod` is the *modulo value* for `s_i`.
`d_mod` is the *modulo value* for `d_i`.
`len` is the *length of the region* to copy.

### Illustration

Illustrating the blocks (`free`, `f1`, `f2`, `f3`, and `f4` are free blocks; `source`, `s1`, and `s2` are source blocks; `dest`, `d1, and` d2`are destinations blocks;`..` is indicating some random width):

```text
A block in a ring buffer can be either (A) one contiguous range,
or (B) two contiguous ranges wrapped at the end:
   start   start+len         (start+len)%size  start
     v         v                     v           v     
+----+---------+----+           +----+-----------+----+
| f1 |  used   | f2 |           | u2 |   free    | u1 |
+----+---------+----+           +----+-----------+----+

So for source and destination, there are basically four cases:
AA: Use memmove() algorithm
+-..-+--------+-..-+
| f1 | source | f2 |
+-..-+--------+-..-+
+-..-+--------+-..-+
| f3 |  dest  | f4 |
+-..-+--------+-..-+

AB: ?
+-..-+--------+-..-+
| f1 | source | f2 |
+-..-+--------+-..-+
+-..-+--....--+-..-+
| d2 |  free  | d1 |
+-..-+--....--+-..-+

BA: ?
+-..-+--....--+-..-+
| s2 |  free  | s1 |
+-..-+--....--+-..-+
+-..-+--------+-..-+
| f1 |  dest  | f2 |
+-..-+--------+-..-+

BB: ?
+-..-+--....--+-..-+
| s2 |  free1 | s1 |
+-..-+--....--+-..-+
+-..-+--....--+-..-+
| d2 |  free2 | d1 |
+-..-+--....--+-..-+
```

### Questions

1. How could a function `int overlaps(unsigned s_i, unsigned d_i, unsigned s_mod, unsigned d_mod, unsigned len)` be written that returns `!= 0` if the *source region* (described by `s_i`, `s_mod`, and `len`) overlaps the *destination region* (described by `d_i`, `d_mod`, and `len`)?
   The idea is to optimize `mod_move()` for non-overlapping regions, possibly using `memcpy()` (or equivalent).
   My first guess is like `s_i + len > d_i || d_i + len > s_i`, but I feel it's incomplete.
2. When deciding whether to use an incrementing or a decrementing index, I need to find out whether the *source region* or the *destination region* has the lower address; does that make any sense in the case of modulo?
3. If there's more than one item to copy it is intended to use either `memmove()` or `memcpy()`, and I wonder how many non-contiguous blocks could exist:
   Four at most?
4. Assuming that `len` is at most the minimum of `s_mod` and `d_mod`, is it guaranteed that an algorithm exists that does not lose any items?
5. The primitive algorithm I would like to replace would be like this:

```c
if (index_increases) {
    while (len-- > 0) {
        items[d_i = (d_i + 1) % d_mod] = items[s_i = (s_i + 1) % s_mod];
    }
} else {
    s_i = (s_i + len - 1) % s_mod;
    d_i = (d_i + len - 1) % d_mod;
    while (len-- > 0) {
        items[d_i = (d_i + d_mod - 1) % d_mod] = items[s_i = (s_i + s_mod - 1) % s_mod];
    }
}
```

6. Is there any special case to consider that I forgot to mention?

### Illustration of the Problem (Failed Example)

Consider this array with numbers (`[23]133` means "*the item at index 23 is 133*"):

```text
[0]110|[1]111|[2]112|[3]113|[4]114|[5]115|[6]116|[7]117|[8]118|[9]119|[10]120|[11]121|[12]122|[13]123|[14]124|[15]125|[16]126|[17]127|[18]128|[19]129|[20]130|[21]131|[22]132|[23]133|[24]134|[25]135|[26]136|[27]137|[28]1|[29]1|[30]1|[31]1|[32]1|[33]1|[34]1|[35]1|[36]1|[37]1|[38]101|[39]102|[40]103|[41]104|[42]105|[43]106|[44]107|[45]108|[46]109
```

And the operation desired is `mod_move(s_i=44, s_mod=47, d_i=0, d_mod=44, len=31)`, meaning "*move 31 items starting from position 44 (modulo 47) to position 0 (modulo 44)*".

Here is an attempt that failed (`DDD: [d] = [s] (n)` meaning "*debug message: array element at `s` containing `n` was copied to element `d`*"):

```text
DDD: [0] = [44] (107)
DDD: [1] = [45] (108)
DDD: [2] = [46] (109)
DDD: [3] = [0] (107)
DDD: [4] = [1] (108)
DDD: [5] = [2] (109)
DDD: [6] = [3] (107)
DDD: [7] = [4] (108)
DDD: [8] = [5] (109)
DDD: [9] = [6] (107)
DDD: [10] = [7] (108)
DDD: [11] = [8] (109)
DDD: [12] = [9] (107)
DDD: [13] = [10] (108)
DDD: [14] = [11] (109)
DDD: [15] = [12] (107)
DDD: [16] = [13] (108)
DDD: [17] = [14] (109)
DDD: [18] = [15] (107)
DDD: [19] = [16] (108)
DDD: [20] = [17] (109)
DDD: [21] = [18] (107)
DDD: [22] = [19] (108)
DDD: [23] = [20] (109)
DDD: [24] = [21] (107)
DDD: [25] = [22] (108)
DDD: [26] = [23] (109)
DDD: [27] = [24] (107)
DDD: [28] = [25] (108)
DDD: [29] = [26] (109)
DDD: [30] = [27] (107)
```

### Another Example

Source size is 35, source position is 27.
Destination size is 27, destination position is 0.
Length is 27.

Original values were:

```text
[0]109|[1]110|[2]111|[3]112|[4]113|[5]114|[6]115|[7]116|[8]117|[9]118|[10]119|[11]120|[12]121|[13]122|[14]123|[15]124|[16]125|[17]126|[18]127|[19]128|[20]129|[21]130|[22]131|[23]132|[24]133|[25]134|[26]135|[27]101|[28]102|[29]103|[30]104|[31]105|[32]106|[33]107|[34]108
```

Incrementing the indices would lead to:

```text
DDD: [0] = [27] (101)
DDD: [1] = [28] (102)
DDD: [2] = [29] (103)
DDD: [3] = [30] (104)
DDD: [4] = [31] (105)
DDD: [5] = [32] (106)
DDD: [6] = [33] (107)
DDD: [7] = [34] (108)
DDD: [8] = [0] (101)
DDD: [9] = [1] (102)
...
```

`[8]` should have gotten value `109`, originally stored in `[0]`.
So you get the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I succeeded with the algorithm (after the fifth basic re-write):
In the attempts before I had solved about 95% of the cases, but the cases left were highly complex, so I inverted the decision tree.

Before doing the actual resize I had to distinguish these three cases:

1. There is enough capacity to keep (and move) all items
2. Items have to be *dropped at the tail* of the queue
3. Items have to be *dropped at the head* of the queue

In addition after handling (2) or (3) more sub-cases could be possible.
I also had realized that I would not be able to find the "dual-modulo array memmove" algorithm that would correctly move overlapping ranges using two modulo numbers.

Instead of distinguishing the configuration cases first, and then handle the
cases (1) through (3), I added code to *drop extra items first*, as
that may alter the basic configuration cases to be handled.

After that I had four cases (from which three possibly could be handled as
one):

- The first three cases are the non-wrapped ones, namely:

  **A**) The allocated items are neither at the start, nor at the end of the array

  **B**) The allocated items are at the end of the array

  **C**) The allocated items are at the beginning of the array
- The final case is the wrapped one:

  **D**) The allocated items wrap at the end of the array

Cases **A**), **B**), and **C**) finally have three sub-cases each, while **D**) finally has two sub-cases.

[image: Four basic configuration cases to consider]

Sub-cases in the image are named **A1** to **A5**, **B1** to **B3**, **C1** to **C3**, and **D1** to **D4**.
The cases **A0**, **B0**, **C0**, and **D0** need no action (size not changed).
**X** (*orange*) are the items to remove, *green* are the new array elements and *red* are the array elements to remove.
*White* elements are not used, while *gray* items are used, but not changed.

Altogether that makes 11 cases to handle.
As said before some further reduction seems possible.

Finally I'd like to note that there is *one case where all elements have to be moved in place*, but I found an algorithm that only needs one extra element.

### Simulation

The verification of my algorithm was done though random simulation
(All the algorithms before failed at some point, but the final one succeeded).

The test algorithms creates a *random-sized queue*, adds a *random number of
items* and shifts the queue by a *random number of positions*.
For simplicity the first item is always number `101`.

Then the test does a number of *queue resizes* and then checks whether the items in the queue are still complete.

The tests for one queue repeat a number of times, just as the test queues
are created 1000 times.

For example "cap=63 ipos=6 count=19" is a queue of capacity 63 with 19 items
starting at position 6:

```text
d=.|.|.|.|.|.|[h=6]101|[7]102|[8]103|[9]104|[10]105|[11]106|[12]107|[13]108|[14]109|[15]110|[16]111|[17]112|[18]113|[19]114|[20]115|[21]116|[22]117|[23]118|[24]119|[t=25]|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.
```

(Empty elements are denoted by `.`, `h` is the head, `t` is the tail position)

After resizing to "cap=25" and using 25 items the array is:

```text
d=[0]120|[1]121|[2]122|[3]123|[4]124|[5]125|[h=t=6]101|[7]102|[8]103|[9]104|[10]105|[11]106|[12]107|[13]108|[14]109|[15]110|[16]111|[17]112|[18]113|[19]114|[20]115|[21]116|[22]117|[23]118|[24]119
```

After resizing to "cap=83" the array is:

```text
d=[0]120|[1]121|[2]122|[3]123|[4]124|[5]125|[h=6]101|[7]102|[8]103|[9]104|[10]105|[11]106|[12]107|[13]108|[14]109|[15]110|[16]111|[17]112|[18]113|[19]114|[20]115|[21]116|[22]117|[23]118|[24]119|[25]120|[26]121|[27]122|[28]123|[29]124|[30]125|[t=31]|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.
```

And after resizing to 22, *dropping at the head* the array is:

```text
d=[0]117|[1]118|[2]119|[3]120|[4]121|[5]122|[6]123|[7]124|[8]125|[h=t=9]104|[10]105|[11]106|[12]107|[13]108|[14]109|[15]110|[16]111|[17]112|[18]113|[19]114|[20]115|[21]116
```